# Users with less than 2k rep cannot edit meta posts

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, editing, suggested-edits

I've edited a number of posts this week, using suggested edits because I don't have 2k on SU yet. It just occurred to me that MSU might also have some posts in need of cleanup, so I came by to check.

However, I don't see an "edit" link underneath any SU posts (except my own).

Is it by design that only "real" editors can edit MSU posts? By design for some other reason? A bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design because the child metas don't really have the traffic for the reviewers to go through the queue.

> #### [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371)
>
> Mostly because the per-site metas are generally low traffic -- some of them count daily visits in the dozens.
>
> That means the moderators will have to do the work, since the 10k site users are the only ones that can even see this queue. And on many sites, like say Bicycles -- there are exactly zero users at this rep level, even after many months.