# Unreview a post

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

Would it be possible to have a feature that allows reviewers to 'unreview' a post? That is, regardless of action taken, push a reviewed post to another user's review queue (or separate queue altogether)?

Comment: An easier to understand solution would be to require action (e.g. clicking a "This post has no problems" button) for it to be considered reviewed.

Comment: Also an alternative, but sometimes I can fix some of the problems with the post, but still be unclear about other parts. Would be nice to have a way to deal with it cleanly.

Comment: Meta downvotes generally mean "I do not agree".

Comment: I like your idea, but the question itself needs 'reviewing'. Fix the grammar. ;)

Comment: @Sathya, I know, but I would like to know why they did not agree. Iglvzx, it's a run on, but feel free to fix it.

Comment: @soandos I do not have the privilege to edit Meta posts.

Comment: @iglvzx, not even suggest an edit?

Comment: @soandos http://meta.superuser.com/a/3391/100787

Comment: I guess just say what is should be changed to in a comment then.

Comment: @soandos I have 2K+ rep now. Edited! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you've done all you think you can on a post, then you've reviewed it. Even if that means doing nothing on it since you've at least read it.

If you want other people to take a look at it, whether because you're unsure of what you've done or if the post could do with more help, you can always post that into the chat room or on meta.