# Suggested edits on child metas

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

While there is [this](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3391/100787) post on the topic, the reasons for it don't really apply anymore, as there is a review pane (complete with a suggested edits page).

As such, I would like to suggest that users in the less than 2k range be allowed to suggest edits on child meta sites (though I suppose that they will not get any rep from it).

If they want to make the meta better, why should we stop them?

Answer (score 2):

To quote from that same post:

> That means the moderators will have to do the work, **since the 10k site
>   users are the only ones that can even see this queue**. And on many
>   sites, like say Bicycles -- there are exactly zero users at this rep
>   level, even after many months.

There really isn't any point. Most Meta posts are only read by higher rep users, or the posts are quickly edited by them themselves. Suggesting edits really isn't useful on Meta - we get almost no traffic here. We don't post very frequently or often enough to really need to edit that much, before someone else gets to it.

I feel it would just be ineffective and never used. I've never seen anyone (outside of that post) asking for this feature either.

Comment: Iglvzx's comment on [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3917/unreview-a-post) post was the inspiration.